# How to find documents from array elements

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, collections, documents

I can't find help in web about it.

I use C# and I have one collection where I stored _ids, usersEmails, and productId (objectId).

Okey, I get whole collection and then I want find in my other collection -"Products" documents which are fit to _id from Products.

short version Collections:

### SmallDictionary

_id as Id, UserEmail, ProductId.

===================================

### Products

_id, Name, Price.

The Products collection has a lot of data, so I don't want make foreach, because it is too long (about 3 secods) I need fastest.

I try used Builder, but doesn't work...

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<SmallDictionary>("SmallDictionary")

var a = collection.Find(x => x.EmailUser == userEmail).ToList();

var filter = Builders<ShopProducts>.Filter.AnyIn(a => a.Id, a);
```

Of course this above doesn't work.

Could somebody help me ? Please :)

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: because the compilator has a problem, because i don't give 
„MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId” „System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ProductCatalog.Model.DocumentClass.LikeDictionary>”. And I can't do it like he want. I think that this should help me                                              db.ShopProducts.find({
    "_id": {
        "$in": [ObjectId("5ae19ed3c7f56f4df84054af"),
ObjectId("5ae19ed3c7f56f4df84054b5"),
ObjectId("5ae19ed3c7f56f4df84054d3"),
ObjectId("5ae19ed3c7f56f4df84054e3")]
    }
});   , but i don't know how implement mongo statement - syntax to c#...

Comment: You may wish to add that detail to your question.